# Caching Dynamic data set in WPF

Tags: wpf, caching

In a WPF application, there is a data set which is being used almost every screen through the application.
That data set is being created dynamically by background process like that
[image]

The Background process will fetch the data in regular interval and make the updated data available to access from every screen.

What I planning is to develop a Global Caching mechanism using
System.Runtime.Caching

I have 3 Data set which is about 2 thousand rows with multiple columns for each data set.
Just wondering whether I might fetch any problem in future for the large data number?

Answer (score 1):

> Just wondering whether I might fetch any problem in future for the large data number?

Whether this is an issue depends on how much memory there is and will be available on your client machines. If you target `Any CPU` or `x64`, the managed heap will grow as needed to basically consume all available address space on a 64-bit machine. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/desktop/Memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#memory-limits-for-windows-and-windows-server-releases) for more information about the limits.

Storing 3 x 2000 objects in a desktop application shouldn't generally be an issue, unless the objects are huge in size.